# Case insensitive JSON to POJO mapping without changing the POJO

Tags: java, json, data-binding, jackson, case-insensitive

Does anyone know how com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper is able to map JSON properties to POJO properties case insensitive?

*JSON-String:*

> [{"FIRSTNAME":"John","LASTNAME":"Doe","DATEOFBIRTH":"1980-07-16T18:25:00.000Z"}]

*POJO-class:*

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

*Test-class:*

```
@Test
public final void testDeserializingPersonJsonToPersonClass()
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    final String jsonAsString = "[{\"FIRSTNAME\":\"John\",\"LASTNAME\":\"Doe\",\"DATEOFBIRTH\":\"1980-07-16T18:25:00.000Z\"}]";
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    final Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonAsString, Person.class);

    assertNotNull(person);
    assertThat(person.getFirstName(), equalTo("John"));
}
```

This ends up in a `JsonMappingException`:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Can not deserialize instance of ...
```

It's not possible to change neither JSON-String nor POJO-Class.

Comment: *It's not possible to change neither JSON-String nor POJO-Class*, then it's not possible.

Answer (score 130):

This behaviour was introduced in Jackson 2.5.0. You can configure the mapper to be case insensitive using MapperFeature.[ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES).

For example :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```

Comment: @deprecated Since 2.13. Now use: `JsonMapper.builder().configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)`

Answer (score 48):

You can solve this problem by configuring the mapper, as described by the @Nicolas Riousset.

In addition, since version Jackson 2.9 you can do the same using annotation `@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)` over a field or class, which is a more flexible option.

```
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
private String firstName;
```

Comment: I tried this in a Spring Boot application that uses jackson 2.9 at minimum and it doesn't seem to have helped.  Is my use case different?  Im optimistic that there is a solution to this but I haven't found anything yet.... I want to believe :)

Comment: @user1445967, how do you use this feature?
Do you have any additional Jackson mapping configuration?

Comment: I am talking about 'ordinary' `@RequestMapping / @GetMapping / @PostMapping` in Spring [Boot] MVC where the `@RequestBody` annotation is placed before an object that is meant to store the JSON properties.  For this reason we do not (intentionally) try to configure any part of Jackson...

Comment: As of May 2020, You CANNOT apply this mapper feature at class level. Such feature is still not implemented. Currently scheduled for Jackson version 2.12 https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1886

Comment: No, the example does not work. The annotation only applies to properties in object of annotated element, not an annotated property itself. There is no single-property case-insensitivity!

Comment: ugh indeed doesn't work, but something similar according to this does work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611062/using-resttemplate-to-map-json-to-object/47612570

Comment: This worked for me even when I applied it to the entire class. (The line above the class).

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a global way of solving this. However you can have 2 setters per property to achieve this:

```
@JsonSetter("FIRSTNAME")
public void setFirstNameCaps(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@JsonSetter("firstName")
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

Not elegant but will work for both upper and lower case json fields. You can also try the solution mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/electrum/1260489) but this might have a performance overhead

Answer (score 13):

## `JsonMapper.builder().configure(...)`

Method <del>[`ObjectMapper.configure()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#configure-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature-boolean-)</del> has been deprecated since Jackson's release version **2.13**.

> **Deprecated**. Since 2.13 use `JsonMapper.builder().enable(...)`

The recommended approach is to one of use overloaded versions of [`configure()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/json/JsonMapper.Builder.html#configure-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.JsonReadFeature-boolean-) method, which is coming from `MapperBuilder` (*parent of* `JsonMapper.Builder` *class)*

*Example:*

```
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
    .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
    .build();
```

## Spring Boot - Application Properties

In a Spring Boot application, this customization can be specified through the Common Application Properties inside the `application.properties` file (*or* `application.yml` *file*).

```
spring.jackson.mapper.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES=true
```

Spring Boot would take care about applying specified feature while configuring `ObjectMapper` at the application startup (*also through properties you can provide, or turn on/off [other Jackson-related properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.json.spring.jackson.constructor-detector) like default locale, serialization features, etc.*).

Answer (score 10):

As of Jackson version 2.12, you can finally annotate on class:

```java
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    // setters and getters ...
}
```

As noted in the [Github issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1886), there is still no support for single-property case-insensitivity!

Comment: Seems to be supported for property too: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1886#issuecomment-1535121638

Comment: @Saikat Did you get it working on property? Still not working for me with Jackson version 2.16.2.

Answer (score 7):

```
package br.com.marcusvoltolim.util;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;

@Log4j
public class JsonUtils {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER;

    static {
        OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
        OBJECT_MAPPER.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        OBJECT_MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(final String json, final Class<T> classe) {
        try {
            return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(json, classe);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
            try {
                return classe.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants to handle this at field level in the POJO itself, they can use either of two annotations with

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy",with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_VALUES)
```

Or

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy",with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
```

Answer (score -1):

I was in the same kind of situation and had to convert to a map and then copy the values over manually.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

Map<String, String> map = 
    mapper.readValue(jsonAsString, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

Comment: Meaningless answer to question

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.