# Spring Boot + MVC JSON Binding - make case INsensitive in limited scope

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

There are a few tips here about how to make Spring Boot case insensitive in binding JSON to object field names.  An issue I have with this is that it changes the behavior of spring binding across the entire application, and this produces unwanted side-effects (like things breaking completely).

I would like to have a certain controller bind "fieldID" in JSON to a certain java object with a field named "fieldId".  Is there a way to do this by tweaking a single controller, java object, package, etc, without having widespread consequences for the entire spring [boot] application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058854/case-insensitive-json-to-pojo-mapping-without-changing-the-pojo/36767648
Is this answer not sufficient?

Comment: Saw that, doesn't work at all for me, unfortunately.  I upvoted this answer and commented in hope someone could elaborate.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54888528/1445967