# Java-rest call: Population of value within variable should work for two variables name

Tags: java, rest, deserialization

I am struct in one of the scenarios and want the best solution. My problem statement is :

I want to call the same POST rest service /test/abc with payload

```
{
"emaid"="US12345" 
} 
or {
"emaId"="US12345" 
}
```

with a small change in variable name emaid as "I and i" small and caps case.

while trying with my approach I am getting exception as:

> {"status_code": 2002,
>       "status_message": "Unknown property emaId while deserializing XYZObject{firstName='asd', lastName='asds', email='asdsa@asd.com', mobile='526487', address1='qwewq', address2='wqwewqewq', city='San jose', emaid='null', emaidType='null'}",
>       "timestamp": "2020-01-29T05:41:31Z"
>   }

with the payload containing

```
{
.....
"emaId" : "US1234",                 --- I want both to work with single rest service please Explain
.....
}
```

as JSON.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive JSON to POJO mapping without changing the POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058854/case-insensitive-json-to-pojo-mapping-without-changing-the-pojo)

Comment: @BhanuHoysala This is the perfect answer what I was searching and this will work in my case as well. Thanks lots. Keep Up Good Work. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller mention both the parameters emailid and emailId and set both the parameters as optional parameters.

And manually check for your required parameter.

```
if(emailid !=null){
    // write your logic
}

if(emailId !=null){
    // write your logic
}
```

I hope this perfectly works for you!

Comment: This will not work for me. Thanks

Comment: why it doesn't for you ?

Comment: Because question speaks something else. Thanks @Manikanta