# Jackson @JsonProperty("SoMeVaLuE") to ignore case

Tags: java, json, jackson

*What I am trying to achieve:*

Parse a json using Jackson and JsonProperty, however, the key, while always the same, comes in all flavor of upper lower cases.

*What I tried:*

The input json has a field `{"field": "value"}`

Therefore, in my POJO, I do this:

`public record MyPojo(@JsonProperty("field") String field`

This works, but then, the key comes in different flavor of cases.

i.e. `{"fieLd": "value"}` `{"Field": "value"}` `{"fIEld": "value"}` etc

For now, I use the `@JsonAlias("fieLd")` etc...

But this is not scalable, since there are many permutations of cases.

*Question:*

How to tell Jackson and the JsonProperty to simply ignore the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive JSON to POJO mapping without changing the POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058854/case-insensitive-json-to-pojo-mapping-without-changing-the-pojo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest putting the json to some kind of pre-processing-step to normalize property Names before Jackons does its json to object mapping

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {
   @Override
   public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
       ObjectCodec codec = jsonParser.getCodec();
       JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jsonParser);
       ObjectNode normalizedNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

       // Normalize property names
       Iterator<String> fieldNames = node.fieldNames();
       while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
           String originalPropertyName = fieldNames.next();
           String normalizedPropertyName = normalizePropertyName(originalPropertyName);
           normalizedNode.set(normalizedPropertyName, node.get(originalPropertyName));
       }

       ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) codec;
       JsonParser modifiedJsonParser = mapper.treeAsTokens(normalizedNode);
       return mapper.readValue(modifiedJsonParser, MyObject.class);
   }

   private String normalizePropertyName(String propertyName) {
       // Perform your normalization logic here
       // For example, convert to lowercase or replace spaces with underscores
       return propertyName.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "_");
   }
}
```

and then wire up the deserializer as you see fit, for example by annotating the target Class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
public class MyObject {
    // ...
}
```